# Converting a netCDF4 file to (georeferenced) GeoTIFF, problems with georeferencing

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdal-translate, sentinel-snap

Let's assume a netCDF4 (.nc) file downloaded from https://s5phub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('e6e91b26-ca43-43d4-9c08-c9c14dd6737e')/$value . This is sulphur dioxide measurement dataset over Vietnam, China and Filippines, given in the linked image.

[image: Sulphur dioxide data over Vietnam, China and Filippines]

I wish to transform this into a GeoTIFF file for further processing so that I can process the values in `(lon, lat, value)` manner. I start by the following command line `gdal_translate -ot float32 -unscale -CO COMPRESS=deflate HDF5:"S5P_NRTI_L2__SO2____20181030T054006_20181030T054506_05418_01_010102_20181030T062719.nc"://PRODUCT/sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column so2.tif`.

When I open the resulting GeoTIFF file, it's almost pitch black with some little grey dots. Using Panoply to plot a diagram produces the following

[image]

I also see in the metadata there reads

```
float sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column(time=1, scanline=278, ground_pixel=450);
:_FillValue = 9.96921E36f; // float
:units = "mol m-2";
:standard_name = "atmosphere_mole_content_of_sulfur_dioxide";
:long_name = "total vertical column of sulfur dioxide for the polluted scenario derived from the total slant column";
:coordinates = "/PRODUCT/longitude /PRODUCT/latitude";
:multiplication_factor_to_convert_to_DU = 2241.15f; // float
:multiplication_factor_to_convert_to_molecules_percm2 = 6.02214E19f; // float
:_ChunkSizes = 1U, 278U, 450U; // uint
```

**Question:**

Do I make this right so that the data values are correct if I intend to use them later as (lon, lat, value) (with WGS84 projection, read from metadata) in various calculations?

E.g. that I don't accidentally corrupt the coordinates or the data values (by accidentally scaling, say). Put otherway, I'm a n00b and asking if this method of using the tooling is OK before banging my head further. I'm still in process of learning the other parts of data processing and checking the correctness of those steps would be easier if I were sure about this step.

<edit 1: Looking at the tiff metadata, it doesn't appear the data is georeferenced. However `gdalwarp so2.tif so2georef.tif -t_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"` fails with

> ERROR 1: The transformation is already "north up" or a transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates cannot be computed for so2georef.tif. There is no affine transformation and no GCPs. Specify transformation option SRC_METH OD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM to bypass this check.

It think this is further confirmed by `gdal_translate -of XYZ so2.tif so2.xyz` that shows values beginning with

```
0.5 0.5 9.96920996838686905e+36
1.5 0.5 9.96920996838686905e+36
2.5 0.5 -2.67918767349328846e-06
3.5 0.5 0.000152658714796416461
4.5 0.5 -0.000818965549115091562
5.5 0.5 0.000193428524653427303
6.5 0.5 0.00010718178964452818
7.5 0.5 -0.00120470335241407156
8.5 0.5 0.000939452263992279768
```

So either something is wrong with the initial command or the original `.nc` file data needs to be augmented. I'm currently too rookie to understand all the metadata but I do see the portal has shapefiles etc.

<edit 2: It appears the glitch was about environment variables and doing a bit of fiddling with that, a new command line I tried is `gdal_translate -ot float32 -unscale -CO COMPRESS=deflate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 HDF5:"S5P_NRTI_L2__SO2____20181030T054006_20181030T054506_05418_01_010102_20181030T062719.nc"://PRODUCT/sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column so2.tif`

So I added `-of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326` and it appears the values I get to the `xyz` file are still the same. It appears the metadata now tells the coordinates are georeferenced, but they aren't really transformed as should, just the metadata added without real transformation. In the metadata I have spotted

```
geolocation_grid_from_band=3
geospatial_lat_max=25.532017
geospatial_lat_min=2.1418159
geospatial_lon_max=99.929924
geospatial_lon_min=128.72141
```

This is probably data that can be explicitly used. If so, might be nice to know if `gdal_translate` could automatically use it, perhaps with an explicit switch.

<edit 3: There's S-P instruction manual at http://www.tropomi.eu/sites/default/files/files/S5P-KNMI-L2-0009-SD-S5P_level_2_Input_Output_Data_Definition-9.0.0-20170614.pdf, from there the following explanation. Then judging from https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html maybe `-a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr 2.1418159 128.72141  25.532017 99.929924` could be added (or in some other order) to the original command line.

[image: S-5P coordinate referencing explanation]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking one question per Question. Please [Edit] this question to focus on one answerable question.

Comment: Check! I removed the more nice-to-know-questions and concentrated only to one question with a reason to ask it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the approximately command line to do this is `gdal_translate -ot float32 -unscale -CO COMPRESS=deflate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr 25.532017 99.929924 2.1418159 128.72141 HDF5:"S5P_NRTI_L2__SO2____20181030T054006_20181030T054506_05418_01_010102_20181030T062719.nc"://PRODUCT/sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column so2.tif`

where the `a_ullr` parameters are derived from the `.nc` file metadata, reproduced here:

```
geolocation_grid_from_band=3
geospatial_lat_max=25.532017
geospatial_lat_min=2.1418159
geospatial_lon_max=99.929924
geospatial_lon_min=128.72141
```

Applying these produces a geotiff file with the following georeferecing information

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (      25.532,      99.930) ( 25d31'55.26"E, 99d55'47.73"N)
Lower Left  (      25.532,     128.721) ( 25d31'55.26"E,128d43'17.08"N)
Upper Right (       2.142,      99.930) (  2d 8'30.54"E, 99d55'47.73"N)
Lower Right (       2.142,     128.721) (  2d 8'30.54"E,128d43'17.08"N)
Center      (      13.837,     114.326) ( 13d50'12.90"E,114d19'32.40"N)
```

Where the `Upper Left` and `Lower Right` are approximately correct but otherwise `Lower Left` and `Upper Right` have switched places. Also comparing the ESA satellite image (linked) and then inserting the corner coordinates to Google Maps yield slightly different places on the map. I tried to project with `EPSG:3857` already and I tried placing the corder coordinates in different order, no dice. That's a different set of questions though. I leave this here in case someone finds it useful, a follow up at [GeoTIFF (ESA Copernicus data) georeferencing coordinates are mirrored and projection slightly off when checking on Google Maps](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300825/geotiff-esa-copernicus-data-georeferencing-coordinates-are-mirrored-and-projec) .