# GeoTIFF (ESA Copernicus data) georeferencing coordinates are mirrored and projection slightly off when checking on Google Maps

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, netcdf, gdal-translate, copernicus

I worked on downloading a Sentinel 5P data in my question at [Converting a netCDF4 file to (georeferenced) GeoTIFF, problems with georeferencing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300755/converting-a-netcdf4-file-to-georeferenced-geotiff-problems-with-georeferenci) and also transforming the netCDF4 (.nc) file into a geoTIFF image/raster data set.

As noted in the answer to my question, it appears the georeferencing method I use doesn't work correctly.

1. Two of the corner points are flipped and for a reason or another I don't seem to get them correctly.
2. I use Google Maps to check I have transformed the geoTIFF file correctly. In addition. The corner points are also slightly off of what Copernicus map shows. I assume this is a difference in the way they project the maps, but as the ultimate goal is to get the tiff on a common web map, I think I need to get this part right too.

**Question:** Can someone shed light on what's wrong with my projection parameters? The parameters are given in the following, first a bit of setup to make it easier to undersand what I was thinking.

I replicate the previous question here as appropriate for this one. In case it helps, the Copernicus portal is at https://s5phub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home. The guest *username* and *password* are given in a prompt when one presses login. It has a lot more tooling to fiddle with ideas, shapefiles amongst other things.

Let's assume a netCDF4 (.nc) file downloaded from `https://s5phub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('e6e91b26-ca43-43d4-9c08-c9c14dd6737e')/$value` . This is sulphur dioxide measurement dataset over Vietnam, China, Taiwan and Philippines, given in the linked image. Regarding the portal, searching with `S5P_NRTI_L2__SO2____20181030T054006_20181030T054506_05418_01_010102_20181030T062719` yields the same data/file as downloading directly.

[image: Sulphur dioxide data over Vietnam, China and Filippines]

From the downloaded `.nc` file I can see in the metadata

```
geolocation_grid_from_band=3
geospatial_lat_max=25.532017
geospatial_lat_min=2.1418159
geospatial_lon_max=99.929924
geospatial_lon_min=128.72141
```

so I proceed the create a geoTIFF raster data file as follows: `gdal_translate -ot float32 -unscale -CO COMPRESS=deflate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr 25.532017 99.929924 2.1418159 128.72141 HDF5:"S5P_NRTI_L2__SO2____20181030T054006_20181030T054506_05418_01_010102_20181030T062719.nc"://PRODUCT/sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column so2.tif`

Applying these produces a geotiff file with the following georeferecing information

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (      25.532,      99.930) ( 25d31'55.26"E, 99d55'47.73"N)
Lower Left  (      25.532,     128.721) ( 25d31'55.26"E,128d43'17.08"N)
Upper Right (       2.142,      99.930) (  2d 8'30.54"E, 99d55'47.73"N)
Lower Right (       2.142,     128.721) (  2d 8'30.54"E,128d43'17.08"N)
Center      (      13.837,     114.326) ( 13d50'12.90"E,114d19'32.40"N)
```

Where the `Upper Left` and `Lower Right` are approximately correct but otherwise `Lower Left` and `Upper Right` have switched places. Also comparing the ESA satellite image (linked) and then inserting the corner coordinates to Google Maps yield slightly different places on the map. I tried to project with `EPSG:3857` already and I tried placing the corder coordinates in different order, no dice (as an aside, it'd be nice to know if this can be done without dumping metadata about the corner points first and applying the information specifically).

Here are the Google Maps links for the corner points for convenience:

- Upper Left: [https://www.google.com/maps/place/25°31'55.2"N+99°55'48.0"E/@28.0950673,105.9647385,5.5z](https://www.google.com/maps/place/25%C2%B031'55.2"N+99%C2%B055'48.0"E/@28.0950673,105.9647385,5.5z)
- Lower Left (inverted): [https://www.google.com/maps/place/25°31'55.2"N+128°43'15.6"E/@25.1936751,127.712565,7.5z/](https://www.google.com/maps/place/25%C2%B031'55.2"N+128%C2%B043'15.6"E/@25.1936751,127.712565,7.5z/)
- Upper Right (inverted): [https://www.google.com/maps/place/2°08'31.2"N+99°55'48.0"E/@1.9855769,100.0484641,7.75z/](https://www.google.com/maps/place/2%C2%B008'31.2"N+99%C2%B055'48.0"E/@1.9855769,100.0484641,7.75z/)
- Lower Right: [https://www.google.com/maps/place/2°08'31.2"N+99°55'48.0"E/@1.9855769,100.0484641,7.75z/](https://www.google.com/maps/place/2%C2%B008'31.2"N+99%C2%B055'48.0"E/@1.9855769,100.0484641,7.75z/)

<edit: With the proposed parameters `-a_ullr 99.930 25.532017 128.72141 2.142` `gdalinfo so2.tif` gives

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  99.9300000,  25.5320170)
Lower Left  (  99.9300000,   2.1420000)
Upper Right ( 128.7214100,  25.5320170)
Lower Right ( 128.7214100,   2.1420000)
Center      ( 114.3257050,  13.8370085)
```

which doesn't seem be right. Looking at the coordinates, it gives a feeling the corners are on straight lines, like a square on a flat map. I'll be spelunking something with "spherical Mercator" soon, I suppose. Basically waving hands to every direction and seeing if something sticks. :P

<edit 5: Maybe it's something about snapping values to pixel colors, i.e. a drawing artifact. Here's another way of seeing the image after removing sentinel values:

[image: SO2 image, without the black band]

<edit 4:

On QGIS looking at metadata about sentinel values and setting their opacity to 100% crops of the edges and reveals a black image that looks like the original. Then adjusting the histogram so that the maximum value is the highest measurement point gives the grey scale image in the picture. The black band on the left side seems to be all minimum values. I don't know the cause of this. It could be a projection artefact but it could also be invalid QA values that should be cropped off. Here's the image:

[image: sentinel value opacity set to 100% and histogram adjusted]

<edit 3:

I proceed with the instructions hinted by @AndreJ and run the following commands

```
gdal_translate -of VRT HDF5:"S5P_NRTI_L2__SO2____20181030T054006_20181030T054506_05418_01_010102_20181030T062719.nc"://PRODUCT/longitude lon.vrt
gdal_translate -of VRT HDF5:"S5P_NRTI_L2__SO2____20181030T054006_20181030T054506_05418_01_010102_20181030T062719.nc"://PRODUCT/latitude lat.vrt
gdal_translate -of VRT HDF5:"S5P_NRTI_L2__SO2____20181030T054006_20181030T054506_05418_01_010102_20181030T062719.nc"://PRODUCT/sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column so2.vrt
```

And modify the resulting `so2.vrt` to read as follows

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="450" rasterYSize="278">
   <Metadata>
   <!-- Snipped off for brevity. -->
   </Metadata>
   <!-- Added this geolocation domain information. -->
   <Metadata domain="GEOLOCATION">
       <mdi key="X_DATASET">lon.vrt</mdi>  
       <mdi key="X_BAND">1</mdi>  
       <mdi key="Y_DATASET">lat.vrt</mdi>  
       <mdi key="Y_BAND">1</mdi>  
       <mdi key="PIXEL_OFFSET">0</mdi>  
       <mdi key="LINE_OFFSET">0</mdi>  
       <mdi key="PIXEL_STEP">1</mdi>  
       <mdi key="LINE_STEP">1</mdi>
   </Metadata>    
   <VRTRasterBand dataType="Float32" band="1">
   <Metadata>
       <MDI key="PRODUCT_sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column_coordinates">/PRODUCT/longitude /PRODUCT/latitude</MDI>
       <MDI key="PRODUCT_sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column_long_name">total vertical column of sulfur dioxide for the polluted scenario derived from the total slant column</MDI>
       <MDI key="PRODUCT_sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column_multiplication_factor_to_convert_to_DU">2241.1499 </MDI>
       <MDI key="PRODUCT_sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column_multiplication_factor_to_convert_to_molecules_percm2">6.02214e+19 </MDI>
       <MDI key="PRODUCT_sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column_standard_name">atmosphere_mole_content_of_sulfur_dioxide</MDI>
       <MDI key="PRODUCT_sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column_units">mol m-2</MDI>
       <MDI key="PRODUCT_sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column__FillValue">9.96921e+36 </MDI>
       <MDI key="PRODUCT_sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column__Netcdf4Dimid">2 </MDI>
     </Metadata>    
     <SimpleSource> 
         <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">HDF5:S5P_NRTI_L2__SO2____20181030T054006_20181030T054506_05418_01_010102_20181030T062719.nc://PRODUCT/sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column</SourceFilename>
         <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
         <SourceProperties RasterXSize="450" RasterYSize="278" DataType="Float32" BlockXSize="450" BlockYSize="278" />
         <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="450" ySize="278" />
         <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="450" ySize="278" />
      </SimpleSource>
 </VRTRasterBand>
 </VRTDataset>
```

Then running `gdalwarp -geoloc -t_srs EPSG:4326 -overwrite so2.vrt so2.tif` and finally `gdalinfo so2.tif` yields

```
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 100.1267700,  25.0621347) (100d 7'36.37"E, 25d 3'43.69"N)
Lower Left  ( 100.1267700,   2.5234540) (100d 7'36.37"E,  2d31'24.43"N)
Upper Right ( 128.5601826,  25.0621347) (128d33'36.66"E, 25d 3'43.69"N)
Lower Right ( 128.5601826,   2.5234540) (128d33'36.66"E,  2d31'24.43"N)
Center      ( 114.3434763,  13.7927944) (114d20'36.51"E, 13d47'34.06"N)
Band 1 Block=493x4 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

which isn't correct. Interestingly the coordinates are "inverted" in that changing `100.1267700,  25.0621347` -> `25.0621347, 100.1267700` is approximately correct, albeit slightly offset when compared to the Copernicus image (looking the coordinates via Google Maps now). It doesn't appear the reason is solely about longitude and latitude information changed but also the projection is wrong.

Opened in QGIS and projected on Google Maps gives [image: SO2 geotiff file] which looks like being in the right place. The data is unscaled so nearly black (I assume), the white strand is an interesting looking thing (looks like being the edge of the original satellite picture, i.e. no data, but why black on the other side then?).

<edit 2: There's interesting discussion at https://github.com/stcorp/harp/issues/189 about possible issues. Even if the discussed issue isn't directly this, one should note it's about Sentinel 5P, georeferencing and invalid values in certain situations. For that I wonder if that's the case here and how to find those values and filter out. As a tangential educative issue, pay attention to vocabulary about level 1/2/3 products too, see more at https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-5p/products-algorithms.

<edit 1: In the metadata I see (I don't know if this matters):

```
PRODUCT_corner_CLASS=DIMENSION_SCALE
PRODUCT_corner_comment=This coordinate variable defines the indices for the pixel corners; index starts a 0 (counter-clockwise, starting from south-western corner of the pixel in ascending part of the orbit).
PRODUCT_corner_long_name=pixel corner index
PRODUCT_corner_NAME=corner
PRODUCT_corner_REFERENCE_LIST=
PRODUCT_corner_units=1
PRODUCT_corner__FillValue=-2147483647
PRODUCT_corner__Netcdf4Dimid=3
PRODUCT_delta_time_long_name=offset from reference start time of measurement
PRODUCT_delta_time_units=milliseconds
PRODUCT_delta_time__FillValue=-2147483647
PRODUCT_delta_time__Netcdf4Dimid=2
PRODUCT_ground_pixel_axis=X
PRODUCT_ground_pixel_CLASS=DIMENSION_SCALE
PRODUCT_ground_pixel_comment=This coordinate variable defines the indices across track, from west to east; index starts at 0
PRODUCT_ground_pixel_long_name=across-track dimension index
PRODUCT_ground_pixel_NAME=ground_pixel
PRODUCT_ground_pixel_REFERENCE_LIST=
PRODUCT_ground_pixel_units=1
PRODUCT_ground_pixel__FillValue=-2147483647
PRODUCT_ground_pixel__Netcdf4Dimid=1
PRODUCT_latitude_bounds=/PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/GEOLOCATIONS/latitude_bounds
PRODUCT_latitude_long_name=pixel center latitude
PRODUCT_latitude_standard_name=latitude
PRODUCT_latitude_units=degrees_north
PRODUCT_latitude_valid_max=90
PRODUCT_latitude_valid_min=-90
PRODUCT_latitude__FillValue=9.96921e+36
PRODUCT_latitude__Netcdf4Dimid=2
PRODUCT_layer_CLASS=DIMENSION_SCALE
PRODUCT_layer_long_name=layer dimension index
PRODUCT_layer_NAME=layer
PRODUCT_layer_REFERENCE_LIST=
PRODUCT_layer_units=1
PRODUCT_layer__Netcdf4Dimid=4
PRODUCT_longitude_bounds=/PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/GEOLOCATIONS/longitude_bounds
PRODUCT_longitude_long_name=pixel center longitude
PRODUCT_longitude_standard_name=longitude
PRODUCT_longitude_units=degrees_east
PRODUCT_longitude_valid_max=180
PRODUCT_longitude_valid_min=-180
PRODUCT_longitude__FillValue=9.96921e+36
PRODUCT_longitude__Netcdf4Dimid=2
```

Comment: GDAL handles coordinates in longitude-latitude and easting-northing order, correct that. But it is odd that in the metadata lon_min is bigger than lon_max.

Comment: I'm a complete rookie both with the tools and knowledge, as might show. Can I ask how would you correct this and/or pointers? Takes awful lot of time to spelunk places and it feels I'd need a tutor! :D I also tried to check the specs at http://www.tropomi.eu/sites/default/files/files/S5P-KNMI-L2-0009-SD-S5P_level_2_Input_Output_Data_Definition-9.0.0-20170614.pdf and some other Copernicus docs. Just to make sure I'm in the correct projection.

Comment: Think "upper-left = least east, most north". So `-a_ullr  99.930 25.532017 128.72141 2.142`. But it can be that your image can't be georeferenced properly with just two corner coordinates but you should see it soon.

Comment: Thanks @user30184. The Copernicus portal is at https://s5phub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home, by the way. The username and password are given in a prompt when one presses login. It has a lot more tooling to fiddle with ideas. On another thought, I think I'll add this note to the OP too.

Comment: It looks like your data has longitude and latitude bands to use. Since the image is bended on your map, `-a_ullr` is not the right tool. You can use it only if the image is expected to be parallel to longitudes and latitudes.

Comment: @AndreJ Can you propose me actions to take or the options? `gdalwarp` perhaps? With what parameters? :)

Comment: Try https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103116/map-project-a-raster-having-separate-latitude-and-longitude-raster-bands

Comment: @AndreJ Cheers! I will, just need to arrange some bandwith (late evening here).

Comment: You might as well look into my answers at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154339/unable-to-warp-hdf5-files and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81361/how-to-reproject-modis-swath-data-to-wgs84

Comment: @AndreJ I think there has been some progress with your advice, but even with your nudge things go wrong. I tried some permuting of the parameters and looking for places, but no luck (knowledge enough) so far. I edited my steps and results if your or someone else have further advice. I feel a bit dumbfounded, I must say. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are already there. I got the same extent as you, and this image:

[image]

Note that the extent of the warped tif is now a rectangle in EPSG:4326, with corners different to the bended satellite view.

The blue dashed line I got from the `METADATA_EOP_METADATA_om:featureOfInterest_eop:multiExtentOf_gml:surfaceMembers_gml:exterior_gml:posList` variable (which uses lat-lon order).

Keep in mind that cell center coordinates and raster extent differ by half the cell size.

---

Update

As requested, this is my batch file:

```
 gdal_translate -of VRT HDF5:"s5p.nc"://PRODUCT/latitude lat.vrt
 gdal_translate -of VRT HDF5:"s5p.nc"://PRODUCT/longitude lon.vrt
 gdal_translate -of VRT HDF5:"s5p.nc"://PRODUCT/sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column s5p.vrt
 gdalwarp -geoloc -t_srs EPSG:4326 -srcnodata 9.96921e+36 -dstnodata 9999 s5p.vrt s5p.tif
```

and the modified vrt file:

```
 <VRTDataset rasterXSize="450" rasterYSize="278">
 <metadata domain="GEOLOCATION">
 <mdi key="X_DATASET">lon.vrt</mdi>
 <mdi key="X_BAND">1</mdi>
 <mdi key="Y_DATASET">lat.vrt</mdi>
 <mdi key="Y_BAND">1</mdi>
 <mdi key="PIXEL_OFFSET">0</mdi>
 <mdi key="LINE_OFFSET">0</mdi>
 <mdi key="PIXEL_STEP">1</mdi>
 <mdi key="LINE_STEP">1</mdi>
 </metadata> 
 <VRTRasterBand band="1" datatype="Float32">
 <SimpleSource>
  <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">HDF5:s5p.nc://PRODUCT/sulfurdioxide_total_vertical_column</SourceFilename>
  <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
  <SourceProperties RasterXSize="450" RasterYSize="278" DataType="Float32" BlockXSize="450" BlockYSize="278" />
  <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="450" ySize="278" />
  <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="450" ySize="278" />
 </SimpleSource>
 </VRTRasterBand>
 </VRTDataset>
```

Comment: So that blue dashed line is in WGS84 system to begin with but I just didn't realize it (since the metadata is in `.nc`)? :) Then if I want to show it on Google Maps, or whatever, then I do the translation and show the square image with, say, alpha channel for edges where there really isn't data.

That is an excellent note about the square and the different order. I could actually accept this an answer, but if I may ask a final question, shouldn't I produce a geotiff image with the coordinates inverted so that `Upper Left` etc. are correct when checked on maps?

Comment: I added a further comment and a image. I don't understand why the white strand in the image. It looks like it goes on the edge of actual measurement data, but why is its left side (the western side) then again black? It feels like there's something wrong in the transformation still, but I don't know. It feels strange it's all black if there isn't measurement data. I think I need to check the fill values or something to clarify this...

Comment: I used `-srcnodata 9.96921e+36 -dstnodata 9999` in my command line.

Answer (score 4):

In case this is useful to anyone, I created a Python script that replicates the accepted answer and that can be used on a number of S5p files for a list of variables, without having to manually edit the vrt file. The code is available [here](https://github.com/lforesta/air-pollution/blob/master/s5p_utils.py), but I also copy-paste below.
EDIT: I updated the code to automatically mask invalid pixels based on the qa_value subdataset stored in the NETCDF file.

```
import os
import subprocess
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np


def write_s5p_tif(in_filepath, variables, output_folder, EPSG_code="4326", spatial_res=[]):
    """
    Write specified variables of S5p NETCDF file to a georeferenced GTiff file 
    in Pseudo-Mercator with spatial resolution 3500m x 7000m.

    Parameters
    ----------
    in_filepath: str
        full filepath to S5p NETCDF file (.nc)
    variables: list of str
        list of variables in the S5p NETCDF file that will be written to GTiff files
    EPSG_code: str
        EPSG code of desired projection, default is 3857 (Pseudo-Mercator)
    spatial_res: list of float
        X and Y spatial resolution (sampling) in degrees or meters according to the chosen projection
        Defaults to 3500m x 7000m (or degree equivalent scaled by mean latitude)

    """

    kwargs = {}
    kwargs['EPSG_code'] = EPSG_code
    kwargs['spatial_res'] = spatial_res

    # Create vrt files for latitude and longitude variables
    geo_params = {}
    geo_params['outputSRS'] = f"EPSG:{EPSG_code}"
    gdal.Translate("lat.vrt", f'HDF5:"{in_filepath}"://PRODUCT/latitude', **geo_params)
    lat_ds = gdal.Open("lat.vrt")
    lats = lat_ds.ReadAsArray()
    gdal.Translate("lon.vrt", gdal.Open(f'HDF5:"{in_filepath}"://PRODUCT/longitude'), **geo_params)

    ds = gdal.Open(in_filepath)
    md = ds.GetMetadata()

    data_var = "temp_s5p.tif"
    mask_var = "qa_value.tif"
    output_file = generate_out_filepath(in_filepath, output_folder, ".tif")

    for variable in variables:
        # Georeference variable datset
        write_var_to_tif(data_var, in_filepath, variable, "lon.vrt", "lat.vrt", lat_ds,
                      **kwargs)
        # Georeference quality_value datset
        write_var_to_tif(mask_var, in_filepath, "qa_value", "lon.vrt", "lat.vrt", lat_ds,
                      **kwargs)
        # Apply quality mask to variable dataset
        write_masked_data(output_file, data_var, mask_var, mask_threshold=75)

        # Clean
        os.remove(data_var)
        os.remove(data_var.split('.')[0] + '_.vrt')
        os.remove(mask_var)
        os.remove(mask_var.split('.')[0] + '_.vrt')

    # Remove vrt files
    os.remove('lon.vrt')
    os.remove('lat.vrt')


def write_var_to_tif(out_filepath, in_filepath, variable, lon_file, lat_file, ds, **kwargs):
    """

    """

    vrt_filepath = out_filepath.split('.')[0] + '_.vrt'

    with open(vrt_filepath, "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write(f"""
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="{ds.RasterXSize}" rasterYSize="{ds.RasterYSize}">
    <metadata domain="GEOLOCATION">
        <mdi key="X_DATASET">{lon_file}</mdi>
        <mdi key="X_BAND">1</mdi>
        <mdi key="Y_DATASET">{lat_file}</mdi>
        <mdi key="Y_BAND">1</mdi>
        <mdi key="PIXEL_OFFSET">0</mdi>
        <mdi key="LINE_OFFSET">0</mdi>
        <mdi key="PIXEL_STEP">1</mdi>
        <mdi key="LINE_STEP">1</mdi>
    </metadata> 
    <VRTRasterBand band="1" datatype="Float32">
        <SimpleSource>
            <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">HDF5:{in_filepath}://PRODUCT/{variable}</SourceFilename>
            <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
            <SourceProperties RasterXSize="{ds.RasterXSize}" RasterYSize="{ds.RasterYSize}" DataType="Float32" BlockXSize="{ds.RasterXSize}" BlockYSize="{ds.RasterYSize}" />
            <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="{ds.RasterXSize}" ySize="{ds.RasterYSize}" />
            <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="{ds.RasterXSize}" ySize="{ds.RasterYSize}" />
        </SimpleSource>
    </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
""")

    # Add georeferencing to vrt file
    georef_data(out_filepath, vrt_filepath, vrt=False, **kwargs)


def write_masked_data(out_filepath, data_file, mask_file, mask_threshold=75):
    """

    """

    data_ds = gdal.Open(data_file)
    data = data_ds.ReadAsArray()
    mask = gdal.Open(mask_file).ReadAsArray()
    data[mask <= mask_threshold] = np.nan

    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    dataset = driver.Create(
        out_filepath,
        data_ds.RasterXSize,
        data_ds.RasterYSize,
        1,
        gdal.GDT_Float32, )

    dataset.SetGeoTransform(data_ds.GetGeoTransform())  
    dataset.SetProjection(data_ds.GetProjectionRef())
    dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(data)
    dataset.FlushCache()  # Write to disk.


def georef_data(out_filepath, in_filepath, vrt, EPSG_code, spatial_res):
    """

    """

    params = {}
    #params['geoloc'] = True
    #params['srcNodata'] = float(md[f"PRODUCT_{variable}__FillValue"])
    params['dstNodata'] = -9999
    params['dstSRS'] = f"EPSG:{EPSG_code}"
    if vrt:
        params["format"] = "VRT"
        #ext = ".vrt"
        out_filepath = out_filepath.replace('.tif', '.vrt')
    else:
        params["format"] = "Gtiff"
        #ext = ".tif"
        out_filepath = out_filepath.replace('.vrt', '.tif')
    if not spatial_res:
        if EPSG_code == "4326":
            params['xRes'] = 0.06288  # equivalent to 7000 meters
            params['yRes'] = 0.06288  # equivalent to 7000 meters
        else:
            params['xRes'] = 7000  # meters
            params['xRes'] = 7000  # meters
    else:
        params['xRes'] = spatial_res[0]
        params['xRes'] = spatial_res[1]

    #out_filepath = generate_out_filepath(in_filepath, output_folder, ext)
    gdal.Warp(out_filepath, in_filepath, **params)



def generate_out_filepath(in_filepath, output_folder, ext):
    """


    ext: '.tif', '.vrt'

    """

    filename = in_filepath.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
    var_name_short = filename[13:20].replace('_','')
    timestamp = filename[20:35]
    return output_folder + os.path.sep + var_name_short + '_' + timestamp + ext


def merge_rasters(in_filenames, output_filename):
    """

    """

    cmd_gdal_merge = " ".join([
                                'gdal_merge.py', '-init 255 -o', output_filename, \
                                '-n 9999' \
                                ] + \
                                ['"%s"' % in_filename for in_filename in in_filenames])
    subprocess.check_output(cmd_gdal_merge, shell=True)
```

Once saved as a file, one can import the function 'write_s5p_tif' and use it this way:

```
write_s5p_tif('S5P_OFFL_L2__NO2____20191222T123026_20191222T141156_11352_01_010302_20191224T055628.nc', ['nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column'], '/path/to/folder')
```

Comment: This is great! This does not remove sentinel values or other invalid values (as noted in netCDF metadata) so could be one quite essential thing to automate too. I have also thought about if there is a better way than these intermediate files, but unlikely there is. And then turning these into MapBox vector (pbuf) files. :)

Comment: Thanks, glad it was useful :)
Fair point about the invalid values, I updated the code to automatically mask them (see edited answer and code). It is not super efficient, since it writes 3 files to disk, but I could not yet manage to do the same with a gdal pixel function and vrt files (which would do all in memory). It still takes only a few seconds (per file) on my laptop though.
About MapBox, I have no experience with it.

Comment: Curiously this is more that one can find online, I think. It's not easy to find example on how to use GDAL, let alone how to use it efficiently or correctly.

Comment: @curiousmind I've facing some issues to open Sentinel 5 data and tried to use your script without success. There is any updates from it?